# Working with multiple column RDD in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I've read through a number of Spark examples, and I can't seem to find out how to create an RDD with with a key column and multiple value columns from a CSV file.

I've read a little bit about Spark SQL and don't think it's what I want in this case. I'm not looking for interactive analysis with this data, more of a batch type processing.

I'm interested in Java or Scala syntax.

Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: I disagree this is too broad a question. I am not asking how to work with CSVs in Spark, I'm asking how to do something rather specific.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html but within Spark?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Multiple column RDD

There's no such thing really, but nor do you *need* one. You can create an RDD of objects with any type `T`. This type should model a record, so a record with multiple columns can be of type `Array[String]`, `Seq[AnyRef]`, or whatever best models your data. In Scala, the best choice (for type safety and code readability) is usually using a **case class** that represents a record.

For example, if your CSV looks like this:

```
+---------+-------------------+--------+-------------+
| ID      | Name              | Age    | Department  |
+---------+-------------------+--------+-------------+
| 1       | John Smith        | 29     | Dev         |
| 2       | William Black     | 31     | Finance     |
| 3       | Nancy Stevens     | 32     | Dev         |
+---------+-------------------+--------+-------------+
```

You could, for example:

```
case class Record(id: Long, name: String, age: Int, department: String)

val input: RDD[String] = sparkContext.textFile("./file")
val parsed: RDD[Record] = input.map(/* split string and create new Record */)
```

Now you can conveniently perform transformations on this RDD, for example if you want to transform it into a PairRDD with the ID as key, simply call `keyBy`:

```
val keyed: RDD[(Int, Record)] = parsed.keyBy(_.id)
```

**That said** - even though you're more interested in "batch processing" and not analysis - this could still be achieved more easily (and perhaps perform better, depending on what you do with this RDD) using the DataFrames API - it has good facilities for reading CSVs safely (e.g. [spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv)), and for treating data as columns without the need to create case classes matching each type of record.