# How to import csv files with massive column count into Apache Spark 2.0

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm running into a problem importing multiple small csv files with over `250000 columns of float64` into Apache Spark 2.0 running as a Google Dataproc cluster. There are a handful of string columns but only really interested in 1 as the class label.

When I run the following in pyspark

```
csvdata = spark.read.csv("gs://[bucket]/csv/*.csv", header=True,mode="DROPMALFORMED")
```

I get a

> File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py",
>   line 312, in get_return_value py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error
>   occurred while calling o53.csv.
>       : com.univocity.parsers.common.TextParsingException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException - 20480
>       **Hint: Number of columns processed may have exceeded limit of 20480 columns. Use settings.setMaxColumns(int) to define the maximum
>   number of columns your input can have**
>       Ensure your configuration is correct, with delimiters, quotes and escape sequences that match the input format you are trying to parse
>       Parser Configuration: CsvParserSettings:

1. Where/how do I set the maximum columns for the parser to use the
   data for machine learning.
2. Is there a better way to ingest the data for use with Apache mllib?

[This question points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36135697/working-with-multiple-column-rdd-in-spark) to defining a class for the dataframe to use but would it be possible to define such a large class without having to create 210,000 entries?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `option`:

```
spark.read.option("maxColumns", n).csv(...)
```

where `n` is number of columns.

Comment: When I ran that I got this `ivysettings.xml file not found in HIVE_HOME or HIVE_CONF_DIR,/etc/hive/conf.dist/ivysettings.xml will be used` The data was imported but the float64 were detected as strings according to `df.printSchema()`

Comment: Warning is unrelated and string types is expected. Unless you infer (and you shouldn't) or provide schema it uses strings.

Comment: It is possible to easily identify all the float64 as features for mllib?